What list style resources questions should this site have
Based on our discussions we are looking at coming up with some good quality questions that will be of high value to this sites users.
Please provide suggestions below, one per answer of resource questions that you think we should have on the site. Top voted suggestions that are also on topic will be graduated to the main site.

On-topic guidelines:
Please avoid subjective questions such as "what are some good... for...." e.g. "What are some good TV series for beginners". A better question is "What are some good quality sites for streaming Chinese TV series?".
For questions about beginner level resources etc. if a person isn't willing to spend some time browsing the sites as provided above or is still finding it difficult, a follow up question such as "What should a beginner be looking for when selecting a TV series?".

Please help the decision process by voting up or down in favor.

I am not sure about suggesting sites that sell, it might become something like a advertising thing... no?

@Alenanno - I think because these types of sites are difficult to find outside of China. The aim of many of these questions is "Where can I get ...", not everything is free, so I think it's something that can't be avoided.

What are some good quality podcasts for learning Chinese
Please include links in your answer and include information at which level the podcast is for (beginner, advanced etc.).
Could be beneficial if you provide how current the podcast is and approximate number of episodes.

And also if it's going to live for a long time? We don't want podcasts that are going to stop at 20 episodes...

What are some sites that provide quality TV streams outside of China?
Provide a link in your answer and a description of the type of shows provide (TV series, sports, variety etc.)

Note for readers: Obviously official sites.

Quality online retailers for Chinese novels
Which online retailers provide a range of Chinese novels that also ship overseas. Would be helpful if the site also provides recommendations and user reviews.

My proposal is that we shouldn't have too many CW. It would be too much... For now I thought of two. If you agree, vote up, if not, vote down... If you have proposals, comment!


Resources for learning Chinese (Textbooks, online courses, podcasts, audiobooks, books)
Methods for learning Chinese (SRS, audio, video, exercises, etc)


